# advised by org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image]I am using spring + Hibernate. I am Getting following error in Servlet.context.xml

```
 advised by org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)
```

is this error? How to solve this? I am trying sessionfactory bean configuration in servlet.context.xml meanwhile I am getting this type of error.

Comment: show your stacktrace...seems to be jars mismatch

Comment: No show the exception stacktrace...e.printStackTrace()